# After dynamically creating html elements, is there anyway to fire an event?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, .net-3.5, dynamic-html

This is a goofy question, so sorry about that.

I'm creating html elements dynamically from an ASP.NET server control. After an element is created, or all of the elments are created, is there a way to force an event to fire on one of them? I understand that it's coming from the server to the client, but I'm looking for a way around that. Is there anything in the document that can listen for html being added or anything?

I'm creating the controls like this:

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
    // htmlString is a dynamically built string of html
    output.Write(htmlString);
}
```

The elements are a series of cascading drop-downs of which the user has the ability to save the selected value. So, if I select the value of the item when I create it, there's no way to kick off the event, which calls out to the database for data to fill its dependent control. There's a "no postbacks" rule here (not my rule).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can output javascript as part of the rendering and [bind events](http://triaslama.wordpress.com/2008/07/22/four-ways-javascript-binding-event-listeners/) to the dynamically created controls.

jQuery makes [binding events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) very easy.

Comment: So, would you recommend that I attach a method to window.onload() to basically fire those events and trigger the cascading? Or do you think there's a better way? Thx, btw. Very helpful.

Comment: @Yatrix - the jQuery idiomatic way is to use `$(document).ready` passing in a function that will attach to the wanted elements.

Comment: Cool - this solves my problem perfectly after banging my client-newbie head against the wall for a few hours. Again, appreciate your help. A lot of folks don't support their answer at all after it's given/accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, fire a Function() from RegisterClientScriptBlock()

Example useage:

`ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "sas", "<script> alert('Inserted successfully');</script>", false);`

Or you can set up a live event on click etc on those new items.

```
$(document).on('click', '#exampleThing', function () {
    // what you want to do
});
```